# Why is my p:progressBar not displayed, only the number?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have following XHTML file with a progress bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE"/>
    <h:head></h:head>
    <f:event listener="#{mainOp.init}" type="preRenderView" />

    <h:body id="body">
        <pm:page id="page">
            <pm:header title="MyProduct">
            </pm:header>

            <pm:content id="content">
                <p:outputLabel value="..."/>
                <p:graphicImage id="image" rendered="true"
                                value="..."
                                cache="false"/>
                <p:progressBar id="progressBar"
                               value="#{mainOp.progress}"
                               rendered="true"
                               cache="false"
                               labelTemplate="{value}%"
                               style="width:400px; font-size:12px"
                               interval="100"/>
                ...
            </pm:content>

            <pm:footer title="m.MyProduct.info"></pm:footer>
        </pm:page>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

In the correspoding bean, I set the progress propety to 21.

```
@ManagedBean(name = MainOpView.NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class MainOpView {
    public static final String NAME = "mainOp";
    [...]

    private Integer progress = 0;

    public void init()
    {
        [...]

        progress = 21;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(final Integer aProgress) {
        progress = aProgress;
    }
}
```

When the page is rendered, I can see the `21 %` lettering, but not the progress bar itself.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I fix it (make the progress bar visible) ?

**Update 1 (27.12.2014 13:43 MSK):** I'm using Primefaces 5.1.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: A very side note : "*The attribute cache is not defined in the component progressBar*".

Comment: @BalusC See update 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is two-fold.

First problem is a bug in `primefaces:primefaces-mobile.js` which exposes as follows in browser's JS console (noted should be that I removed the `<p:graphicImage>` to reduce noise):

[image]

It appears that the `<p:progressBar>` script isn't by default included in PrimeFaces mobile CSS/JS and thus needs to be loaded individually. However, the inline `PrimeFaces.cw(...)` call in the generated HTML output, which is responsible for that, appears to lack the 4th argument which should represent the CSS/JS resource name. See the following extract from the generated HTML output (formatting mine):

```
<script id="page:progressBar_s" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        PrimeFaces.cw(
            "ProgressBar",
            "widget_page_progressBar",
            { id: "page:progressBar", widgetVar: "widget_page_progressBar", initialValue: 21, ajax: false, labelTemplate: "{value}%" }
        );
    });
</script>
```

This causes the CSS/JS resource name to end up as `undefined`:

```
GET http://localhost:8088/playground/javax.faces.resource/undefined/undefined.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1
GET http://localhost:8088/playground/javax.faces.resource/undefined/undefined.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=5.1
```

This is clearly a bug in PrimeFaces mobile. Your best bet is to [report](http://www.primefaces.org/issuetracker) this issue to the PF guys.

In the meanwhile, you can workaround this by executing this script in end of head or begin of body, either inline or via a custom script file:

```
var originalPrimeFacesCw = PrimeFaces.cw;
PrimeFaces.cw = function(name, id, options, resource) {
    resource = resource || name.toLowerCase();
    originalPrimeFacesCw.apply(this, [name, id, options, resource]);
};
```

This basically defaults to lowercased version of widget name when no CSS/JS resource name is defined. Now the progress count appears as bold and there's a space in front of that count:

[image]

This brings us to the second problem. The `.ui-progressbar .ui-widget-beader` CSS is missing the background color in the CSS. On standard (non-mobile) PrimeFaces, this is defined in theme-specific CSS file such as `primefaces-aritso:theme.css`. For mobile PrimeFaces, this style is thus expected in `primefaces:primefaces-mobile.css`, however it contains only the `<p:panel>` style.

I'm here not sure if this is a bug or an oversight in PrimeFaces mobile. Also here, your best bet is to [report](http://www.primefaces.org/issuetracker) this issue to the PF guys.

In the meanwhile, you can get it to style by adding the following CSS in end of head, either inline or via a custom CSS file:

```
.ui-progressbar .ui-widget-header {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

[image]

You might only want to add a tiny border as finishing touch.

Comment: Issue was already reported in PF: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7717, please 'star' the issue